# Не происходит сохранения в базе данных при большом объеме входных данных

Tags: java, база-данных, jdbc

Есть вот такой код заполнения таблицы в БД:

```
private void putDataIntoTableCosts() throws SQLException {
    String query = new String();
    query += "Insert into costs ";
    for (int i = 0; i < task.getCosts().size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < task.getCosts().get(i).size(); j++) {
            query += "(select " + id_task + ',' + (i + 1)
                    + ',' + (j + 1) + ',' + task.getCosts().get(i).get(j)
                    + ')';
            if(j != task.getCosts().get(i).size()-1)
                query += " union ";
        }
    }
    putDataIntoDB(query);
}
```

То есть заполняется она из двумерного массива costs. Когда этот массив небольшой, ну хотя бы 5 на 5 все нормально заполняется. Когда становится больше, 20 на 20 например, уже не сохраняются данные. Получаю вот такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Окончание вывода ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ума не приложу в чем может быть дело.

Comment: Значит ограничения на размер запроса или что то в этом роде. количество таблиц (select) в запросе так же ограничено. А судя по сообжению об ошибке это mysql и insert гораздо короче выходит в виде `insert into tab values(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),...`

Comment: @Mike, да, mysql, спасибо попробую через tab, не знал такого. А что значит ограничение на размер запроса? Я же не ставил никаких ограничений. Это в mysql так?

Comment: Как минимум есть ограничение в 64кб на пакет данных и как я понимаю запрос не может быть больше. Ну и отдельные select - это нагрузка на синтаксический анализатор у него по идее то же должны быть свои ограничения. хотя явной инфы гугл мне не дал, может не так ищу. эммм ... что значит через tab, это я так таблицу назвал :) главное что values можно много в отдельных скобках

Comment: @Mike, ага, понял, поставил вместо tab имя таблицы своей, все получилось, спасибо)